# Android In-app Billing and own data server

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Today I need some help from peoples, who have experience in In-app Billing.

Let I have my own server with digital content for applications from Market and some applications with billing support. User download it from the market and want to buy additional functionality. He paid for it, using billing, and what to to next?

I must invoke some method's of my own server with content from application or Market can send some request to it with information about bought content?

I want to say, logic for downloading bought content must be implemented in application and only from here i can begin to download bought content or market server can send some information to my server with content?

Comment: Have you found any solution. I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the sample billing app provided by Google. Logically, after you have purchased something. You will receive an intent via a broadcastreceiver. This intent have all the information you need to make a query to ask what the user has purchased. After you have get the whole order info, you can make a call to your own server to verify the purchase and let the application download the content.

Here is the link to the documentation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html
look closely at the Messaging sequence section.